# EWS. How to get latest SyncState without initial synchronization?

Tags: synchronization, exchangewebservices

Consider that I have 100,000 messages in a folder. I want to be able to synchronize with latest changes, but I don't need any old messages. Asking for initial synchronization with

```
SyncFolderItems(..., null /*syncState*/)?
```

would bring back all 100,000 messages (that I don't need). How can I jump directly to the latest SyncState without reading 100,000 entities from server?

Comment: I want to mention another issue: SyncState for folder with 100,000 items will be huge. For my inbox with 11,500 items it is 143,340 characters long.

Answer (score 3):

You can't work around that. You need to iterate through the collection once. After you have processed all existing entries, the syncstate should be much smaller than your 143kb.